# Jquery How to show/hide extra items

Tags: jquery

I have a list which hides all items after showing 2 items. I want to show and hide the items in the individual groups( Show More) when hidden and (Show Less) when expanded. How do I go about doing it?

Here is my code and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/ar6hayp9/11/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // alert("hello");
   // $("div.cards:gt(2)").hide();
    $("div.cards").find("div:gt(4)").hide();
    $("div.cards").has("div:nth-child(5)").after("<p class=\"showhide\">Show More</p>");

});i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple solution using css and jQuery like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.cards").has("div:nth-child(5)").append('<p class="showhide">Show More</p>');
  $("div.cards .showhide").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      $cards = $(this).closest('.cards');
    $cards.toggleClass('open');
    $this.text($cards.hasClass('open') ? 'Show less' : 'Show more')
  });
});
```

```css
.cards > div:nth-child(n+3) {
  display: none;
}
.cards.open > div:nth-child(n+3) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards">
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">b</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">d</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">e</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">f</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cards">
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">.2.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">.3.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">.4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">.5.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="random_cms-class">
    <div class="card">.6.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set up a click event for the `showhide` element that toggles the hidden ones to be visible and vice versa.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cards").find(":gt(4)").hide();
    $(".cards").append("<p class=\"showhide\">Show More</p>");
    $(".cards").on("click", ".showhide", function(ev) {
        var showhide = $(this);
        var container = showhide.parent();
        if (showhide.text() == "Show More") {
            container.find(":gt(4)").show();
            showhide.text("Show Less");
        } else {
            container.find(":gt(4)").hide();
            showhide.text("Show More");
        }
    });
});
```